# Is "to be a better one" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Is "to be a better one" in the following sentence grammatical?

> I need to train my English to be a better one

Comment: To be a better one what? Maybe you wanted to say, "I need to enhance my English to be better" - I need to make my English better in order to be better. **English** is always capitalized in English. And the word **train** doesn't really fit here, you cannon train English. And **better one** doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, no, this is not grammatical. Unless **English** refers to something like your English setter or your English sheepdog!

"Your English" is not a countable noun, not a single item, but a set of related skills and ideas, so you would not refer to it in the singular.

The grammatical form of this sentence would probably be more like "**I need to train to improve my English**".

Answer (score 0):

*English* used like this is not a singular countable noun.  It's a singular non-countable noun.  So you can't use *one* to refer to it.

> I need to train my English to be better.

Similarly,

> I need to train my cats to be better.

But you can use *ones* to refer to plural countable nouns.

> I need to train my cats to be better behaved ones.

Comment: Additionally, you can't train English.  To train something you must be able to train it in its entirety.  You can train your dog to sit and you can train your ear to discern octave changes but you cannot train the Atlantic Ocean to do anything.  Same with English.

Comment: "I need to practice my English [good place for a noun here to more finely indicate what it is you need to practice...pronunciation, grammar, prepositions?] in order to be better understood."

Comment: You can train *your English*, just not *the English.*

Comment: I'm not so sure that my English can be trained.  What would it be trained to do?  Something is trained to do something else and you can't train English, yours or mine, to do anything.  Can I train my English to evoke feelings of joy and comfort?  I can train my "pen" to do that.  I can train my "voice" to do that.  English, not so much.

Comment: Then why can you say *My English is not so good?*  It doesn't seem unreasonable to interpret the word "English" as shorthand for "skill/usage of English."

Comment: Because even if it is shorthand for skill or usage -- you still can't train your skill or your usage.  The logic remains the same.  What would you train your skill to do?  You can hone a skill.  What would you train your usage to do?  You can refine your usage or perfect your usage.  What you are "training" is never the/your English.  What you are training is some aspect of YOUR understanding or usage, not the English.